# mirrored mesh not showing up in edit mode

Tags: mirror

Basically, I have added a mirror modifier to my mesh but it is only showing up in object mode and I was wondering how to make it show up in edit mode too

Answer (score 1):

In the *Properties Window > Modifiers Tab > Mirror Modifier* look for the button on the top that reads *Display Modifier in Edit Mode*, the one with the cube with four vertex highlighted.